# Google Depot Tools `gclient runhooks` fails, "SYSTEMROOT" must be valid

Tags: python, google-chrome, chromium

I am attempting to work on [Chrome](http://www.chromium.org/Home) and one of the key commands `gclient runhooks` fails with the error.

```
Exception: Environment variable "SYSTEMROOT" required to be set to valid path
Error: Command C:\Users\noahh_000\Noah\Programing\Chrome\Tools\DepotTools\depot_
tools\python276_bin\python.exe src/build/gyp_chromium returned non-zero exit sta
tus 1 in C:\Users\noahh_000\Noah\Programing\Chrome\Chromuim
Hook ''C:\Users\noahh_000\Noah\Programing\Chrome\Tools\DepotTools\depot_tools\py
thon276_bin\python.exe' src/build/gyp_chromium' took 36.86 secs
```

It seams like the error is

```
Exception: Environment variable "SYSTEMROOT" required to be set to valid path
```

I think this means that the environment variable `SYSTEMROOT` is not defined, however when I look at my System Enviroment variables I see that `SYSTEMROOT` is indeed set

[image: System Environment Vars]

I have also tried changing it to

- C:/WINDOWS
- C:/windows
- C:\WINDOWS
- C:\windows
- C:\WINDOWS
- C:\windows

but none worked.
When I list the environment variables(With `set`) `SystemRoot` is defined but not `SYSTEMROOT`

### System Info

**OS**: *Windows 8*
**Architecture** *x64*

**Edit:** I found where the script throws the exception and I made it output the paths it thinks its getting and it outputs

```
The system cannot find the path specified
```

**Edit2:** It looks like a file that in `depot_tools\win_toolchain\vs2013_files\win8sdk\bin\SetEnv.cmd` has an error. The python script runs the file in a subproccess and tries to get a result, but somewhere in this subproccess a file can not be found, hence the

```
    The system cannot find the path specified
```

[SetEnv.cmd](http://pastebin.com/dGgYyPFL)

Comment: Hmm, I still have not figured this out.

Answer (score 0):

I meet this error after installation VS2015, so I guess problem comes from system environments.
Please check and set the value of GYP_MSVS_VERSION to 2013 as recommended.

```
set GYP_MSVS_VERSION=2013
```

You should set GYP_MSVS_VERSION before running gclient runhooks.

The problem is solved for me by this way. 
Hope this helps.